# load remote html file into grapesjs

Tags: javascript, php, grapesjs

Able to fetch my remote HTML file using load URL and getting status ok, how can I load this fetched HTML AND CSS into editor? currently I'm getting blank screen inside editor.

What I tried so far:

```
storageManager: {
    type: 'remote',
    autosave: false,
    autoload: true,
    contentTypeJson: false,
    setStepsBeforeSave: 1,
    contentTypeJson: true,
    params: {


    },
    storeComponents: true,
    storeStyles: true,
    storeHtml: true,
    storeCss: true,
    urlStore: '../inc/page/edit_builder.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>',
    urlLoad: '../inc/page/fetch_builder.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>',

     headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json_encode:{
    "gjs-html": [],
    "gjs-css": [],
    }
  //headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ...' },
  }

editor.load(res => console.log('Load callback'));
```

From the server

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM mp_pages WHERE page_id='$id'");
$response= array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
                array_push($response, array(
                "gjs-html"=>$row['page_desc'], 
                "gjs-css"=>$row['css']
               ));

}
echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass your remote HTML/CSS to GrapesJs editor. 
In javascript

```
editor.setStyle(Your remote style file)
editor.setComponent(Your remote HTML)
```

[IMPORTANT]

> GrapesJS is able to start from any HTML/CSS but use
>   this approach only for importing already existent HTML templates, once
>   the user starts editing, rely always on JSON objects because the HTML
>   doesn't contain information about your components.

Checkout this link. For Store and load templates
https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Storage.html#store-and-load-templates